# View entire file in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I noticed that when you open an `.exe` file in notepad, it shows up like this:

[image]

But when you open it into a windows forms textbox, it looks like this:

[image]

It's not just for .exe files either. the same thing happens with anything thats not plain text.

Can somebody tell me how I can make my textbox do that?

Comment: Could you post the actual pictures instead of links?

Comment: I will add the pictures.

Comment: You might have enough reputation now. Anyway, how are you loading the file?

Comment: Like this: textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(Path);

Comment: @xtnd8 Why not?   Maybe he wants to make the next generation of text editors?  We should encourage creativity and experimentation not question it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem, the winforms's textbox stops rendering text when it finds a null byte. You can verify it like this:

```
textBox1.Text = "Hello\0World";
```

It'll just show the "Hello" part.

Comment: Same result, just in a different font.

Comment: This will do it: textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(t).Replace("\0", string.Empty);

Comment: Or you could replace with a space or another special character, this way the null byte will still be visible.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like an encoding issue. View the encoding used in notepad and force your textbox to have the same, e.g

```
textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(file,Encoding.UT8);
```

Comment: I tried all of the encodings. They all were still about three characters.